# Updating my ListView in Android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

Hello I want to Update my Listview.

I Have a Listview and it only contains 1 TextView.

This si how I fill that listView:

lView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);

```
        String[] i=new String[1];
        i[0]="hdfsfsfsdfsdfsdhfgsdhgvchjyxvchjyxcjhygchsgdjchgsjgdjsachsa";


        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.main, R.id.textview, i);
        lView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

now I want to dynamically update this string in the lsitview

How can i approach this?

Edit:

Ok I solved with the help of the guy who answered here:

I just need to manipulate the Stringarray and then call notifiyDataChanged() like this:

```
    stringArray[0]=newString;
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the item from the adapter, change it's data, and tell the adapter something changed

```
int index = 0;
String item = adapter.get(index);
item = "my new string";
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

This is all from the [ArrayAdapter API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html)

Comment: I'll try it out... I was allready trying to get the textView with adapter.getItem(Position) but it gave me a string I think this is what I could have also used lol when I think about it

Comment: Yes, adapter gives data. If you want the view you would have to implement the adapter yourself possibly. Check the api :)

Comment: doesnt work theres no get() method but I think you meant getItem....nevertheless I dont see anything

Comment: the listview is just blank I think the changes to the string allthough its an object are jsut local

Comment: Ok I get it now: check my edited answer! I will give you the points for your answer neveretheless :)